# class have an object of selftype

Tags: c++

Want to understand why there is no compilation error

If a class has a static object of same type and the class has parametric constructor why it didnt enfore while creating it

```
class test {

      static test a;
      int b;

      public:
            test(int arg) {
                 b = arg;
              }
};

int main() {
  test t1(100);

  return 0;

}
```

I know that to make it work I need to add as

```
 test test::a(100)
```

but without the above line why there is no compilation error .
Any pointer

Comment: Hey the question is If I don't initialize it with test test::a(100) why there is no error? Why it didnt complain that "candidate expects 1 argument but 0 provided

Comment: `a` is neither defined nor odr-used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If at all, it would be a *linker* error. But as you don't use the static object, the linker won't look for it and thus no build error...

Try this for comparison:

```
int main()
{
    test::a.b = 7; // sure, you need to make the members public for...    
    return 0;
}
```

Now you *do* use the static object – but it wasn't created anywhere and the linker will fail to look it up.